# How to generate a null using Kotlin KClass property simpleName

Tags: kotlin

The spec for `KClass.simpleName` on Kotlin 1.3.41 for Common, JS, JVM and Native is:

> The simple name of the class as it was declared in the source code, or
>   null if the class has no name (if, for example, it is an anonymous
>   object literal).

To generate a null seems straightforward: get the simpleName of the KClass generated from an anonymous object literal. The following code is a failed attempt to do just that:

```
interface Human { fun think(): String }

@Test fun `when finding the name of an anonymous object verify the name is null`() {
    fun start(man: Human) = println(man.think())

    start(object: Human {
        val name = this::class.simpleName
        override fun think() = "Thinking really hard! Name is: $name" // name == 2
    })
}
```

My expectation was that name should be `null`. Why is the value of name 2? How should I change the code to get the value of name to be `null`?

Comment: Maybe its some weird behaviour of your test framework. When I copy-pasted your code into `fun main()` it printed `null` - the same when I pasted it into class function and run it from main method

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the issue. Kotlin 1.3.41

Comment: Unable to reproduce using Kotlin 1.3.41. Could you provide a [mre]? What version of Kotlin are you using? What's your build environment? What testing framework are you using?

Comment: I have at least one report for JS reporting null and JVM reporting 2. Hmmmm

Comment: @dey What JDK/JRE and Kotlin versions did you run your copy on?

Comment: I have filed a bug with JetBrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-32995 and provided a Github repo to illustrate the errant behavior: https://github.com/pajatopmr/kotlinSimpleNameBug

Comment: Still unable to reproduce after cloning your repository when using OpenJDK 12.0.1, Windows 10, and Gradle 4.10/Gradle 5.5.1. Executing `clean build` completes successfully. Test reports show 9 successful tests and 0 failures.

Comment: @Slaw your test run seems to say that the bug could be an OS issue: works on Windows but not on macos/Mojave. Good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code a little bit:

```
interface Human { fun think(): String }

fun main() {

    fun start(man: Human) = println(man.think())

    start(object: Human {
        val name = this::class.java.simpleName
        override fun think() = "Thinking really hard! Name is: $name" // name == 2
    })
}
```

> Why is the value of name 2?

and now let's look at the bytecode for this.
this is part of the bytecode for the `start` function. as you can see it implements `Function0` and it has an `invoke` method that takes a `Human`.

```
final class com/example/customview/TestKt$main$1 extends kotlin/jvm/internal/Lambda implements kotlin/jvm/functions/Function1 {


  // access flags 0x1041
  public synthetic bridge invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    ALOAD 0
    ALOAD 1
    CHECKCAST com/example/customview/Human
    INVOKEVIRTUAL com/example/customview/TestKt$main$1.invoke (Lcom/example/customview/Human;)V
    GETSTATIC kotlin/Unit.INSTANCE : Lkotlin/Unit;
    ARETURN
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 2

  // access flags 0x11
  public final invoke(Lcom/example/customview/Human;)V

   ....
```

and this is part of the bytecode for the anonymous object as you can see it implements `Human`:

```
public final class com/example/customview/TestKt$main$2 implements com/example/customview/Human {

  OUTERCLASS com/example/customview/TestKt main ()V

  // access flags 0x12
  private final Ljava/lang/String; name

   .....
```

you can see from the bytecode that the name of your anonymous class is actually `TestKt$main$2`. because the compiler automatically generated a class for your file that is `TestKt` and another class for the main function that is `TestKt$Main`. then for every function or anonymous class, another class will be generated, and they are named by order. for example, here function `start` has a class with the name `TestKt$main$1` that extends `Lambda` and `Function0`.
if you add a dummy method in between in the main function like this:

```
fun main() {

    fun start(man: Human) = println(man.think())

    fun nothing() = {}

    start(object: Human {
        val name = this::class.java.simpleName
        override fun think() = "Thinking really hard! Name is: $name" // name == 3 this time
    })
}
```

then the name of your class would be `3`
that is the answer for why it's 2

> How should I change the code to get the value of the name to be null?

you can use `qualifiedName` instead of `simpleName`. this must be a mistake in the documentation, just ignore the part in the parenthesis which says "if, for example, it is an anonymous object literal".
this is what the doc says about qualifiedName:

> The fully qualified dot-separated name of the class, or null if the class is local or a class of an anonymous object.

and it works as it said.

```
start(object: Human {
        val name = this::class.qualifiedName
        override fun think() = "Thinking really hard! Name is: $name" // name == null
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get a null from a simpleName in Kotlin is to reference a Java built class, or to literally override the simpleName with the class definition. Kotlin generated classes on the JVM always have a defined simpleName property by default.